# MySQL Type=MyISAM Error

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on my forums website earlier this month and came across a little problem. Unfortunately, everything has gone smoothly except for my database. I was making a table in it called `users` with this script...

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

When I tried to run the code however, I get this error...

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2' at line 6**

I have dealt with this once before by running it with `Engine`, but I got two different errors when I did that this time.

I did some research on it and thought my MySQL code may be outdated, but when I ran the code on the same version of MySQL from my one of my employees computers, it worked fine. After that, I tried running it on an older version of MySQL from my computer again, but still got an error.

My assumption is it may be a simple mistake, or a computer/server error. I would try to just do my website on a different computer, speaking that I own a computer shop, but I don't want to have to start all over since it is localhost. Also, I am at a loss for flash drives and with the weather we have been getting out here in north Scandinavia, there is no way I will be able to get it shipped any time soon.

So, as a last resort I decided to ask you guys. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'll try it again, but the first time I tried I got two different errors

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Strange ones such as Users is already a  table in the database, even if it is a new clean database. I have never seen anything like it

Comment: can you post the errors?

Comment: Like I said, I ran the same version of everything on my employees computer, and it worked fine...

Comment: you already have a 'Users' table in the database.

Comment: Sorry, I know that would help #1050 - Table 'users' already exists

Comment: already have that table too then.

Comment: I would show the other one but I fixed it so I am not worried about that

Comment: it seems like you already have the tables you are trying to create

Comment: @Sam D thanks for your help, I at least know what the problem is. Never heard of it before, gonna be a pain to find it, but at least I know that for some reason when I create a database it is automatically creating a table. I would think this is impossible unless, my php script allows it to do so. Do you think I should ask, another question about it or do you think you know how to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you must change this

```
  TYPE=MyISAM
```

to

```
 ENGINE=MyISAM
```

> TYPE was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5.

documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

Comment: then as i mention , you should upgrade to ENGINE

Comment: @PCJackson if question is solved , make sure to accept answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```