# i am trying to create a simple hibernate application.It gives following error.how to solve that error

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jdbc

MainClass.java

```
package com.binod.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentInfo studentInfo=new StudentInfo();
        studentInfo.setRollNo(1);
        studentInfo.setFirstName("Binod");
        studentInfo.setLastName("Pant");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        // this would save the Student_Info object into the database
        session.save(studentInfo);  
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }
}
```

StudentInfo.java

```
package com.binod.hibernate;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class StudentInfo {

    @Id
    private int rollNo;
    private String firstName,lastName;
    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
 }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">   
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatepractise
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            devbinod
        </property>
        <!-- show all executed sql -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop Existing Table create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.binod.hibernate.StudentInfo" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The Error is

```
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    Hibernate: drop table if exists student
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
    INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@134d26af] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
    Hibernate: create table student (rollNo integer not null, firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), primary key (rollNo)) type=MyISAM
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
    INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@331acdad] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
    WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
        at com.binod.hibernate.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:16)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 13 more

    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
    INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2e2ff723'
    Hibernate: insert into student (firstName, lastName, rollNo) values (?, ?, ?)
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
    ERROR: Table 'hibernatepractise.student' doesn't exist
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
    INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    Jun 11, 2017 8:28:10 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
    ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
        at com.binod.hibernate.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernatepractise.student' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
        ... 18 more
```

I already created a student table.Hibernate drop table but don't create a new table.how to solve this problem.where is my mistake i can't find.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1` check this , looks like this is the main cause.

Comment: @AmitK when i remove  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` property from hibernate.cfg.xml file it work fine.

Comment: instead of ` <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` you should use ` <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` , you dont want to create the Db every time you start the application.

Comment: Thanks @AmitK problem is solve.

Comment: @AmitK i have a no idea when i use `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` table is just drop but not create in my database.please give me idea about that problem

Comment: can you give your create table syntax ?

Comment: `create table student( rollNo int not null,firstName varchar(50),lastName varchar(50), primary key(rollNo));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146343/discussion-between-amitk-and-binod-pant).

Comment: Can you change your MySQL dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and check?

Comment: thanks @N00bPr0grammer my problem is solve.plz explaing `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`  it only drop table but not create

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer ok. i request upvote my question. as you feel

Comment: Already done so!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer thank you.i am also do in your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL dialect when changed from

```
`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
```

to

```
`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`
```

should resolve your issue.

The reason for this to happen is that MySQL5Dialect works with type `MyISAM`

The problem is that the dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` is for `MySQL 4.x` or earlier. The fragment `type=MyISAM` that is generated by this dialect was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in 5.5.

There are quite a few documentations available for what dialects to use for what database engine types for MySQL alone.

Comment: Note that there are also newer versions of the dialect available

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use such declarations :

```
 private String firstName,lastName;
```

use instead :

```
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
```

Also check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937789/mysql-type-myisam-error)

Make sure that you use correct version of Hibernate, JDBC driver and MySQL server

Comment: @Binod Pant if You will open the link, I've added in my answer and check Your logs - You can understand what was going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in **hibernate.cfg.xml** :

`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

to

`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

We do not need to create the schema again, it destroys previous data.
So, update value for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto updates the schema.

Comment: it only destroys previous data but not create new table.I want to reason why after destroying new table it can't create new table.`update` works fine

Comment: Create only destroys data, and does not create or drop the table.

Schema is just a skeleton structure which represents the logical view. Schema is created with create variable in  hbm2ddl.auto, and not the table.
Creating a schema initially is a must for hibernate application. Later on, we should use create or update or validate depending upon our requirement.